# Netbeans incompatible types question

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans6.5, incompatibility

I am getting the following warning in Netbeans:

```
incompatible types
found : carPackage.port.search
required : carPackage.SearchResponse
```

In my JSP page, I have the following code:

```
CarService service = new CarService();
CarPort port = service.getCarPort();
SearchResponse searchResult = port.search("Toyota");
```

The error obviously occurs on this line:

```
SearchResponse searchResult = port.search("Toyota");
```

What datatype should I put in instead of SearchResponse?

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing ; from the end. If CarPort.search returns SearchResponse, then your datatypes are correct.

Comment: sorry. I did have the semi-colons at the end.
Typo. Will edit now.

I am not too sure why...then...the error is displaying.
I have imported the packages correctly as well...

Comment: Netbeans (at least usually) shows you the return types while editing. Try it, write SearchResponse searchResult = port. and you'll see all public methods that port object has, as well as their return types in the rightmost column.